# Search a value in XELement

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, linq-to-xml, xelement

I have a tree in form of `XML` that stores it in `XELement` variable.How I can search a value in **All Nodes** in this XML and if it exists return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool result = element.DescendantsAndSelf().Any(e => e.Value == "cccc");
```

Answer (score 0):

for searching a Value i couldnt find anything and i wrote this :

```
wfo = XElement.Load("some xml");
foreach (var element in wfo.DescendantsAndSelf())
                    {
                            foreach (XAttribute attribute in element.Attributes())
                            {
                                if (attribute.Value.Any(q=>q== "search"))
                                {

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

linq :

> var test = wfo.DescendantsAndSelf().Attributes().Any(q =>
>   q.Value.Any(z=>z == "search"));